# Postgresql WHERE timea = timeb, how to specify the precision?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, postgresql-9.3

I'm doing some work matching time series data from different tables. 
As an example this table has columns for 1 second time series and a 'nearest hour' column like:

```
"datetime"                  "closesthourdatetime"
"01/01/2005 00:30:00"       "01/01/2005 01:00:00"
"01/01/2005 00:30:01"       "01/01/2005 01:00:00"
"01/01/2005 00:30:02"       "01/01/2005 01:00:00"
```

If I run

```
    SELECT time_series_only.closesthourdatetime
    FROM measdata.time_series_only
    WHERE time_series_only.datetime = time_series_only.closesthourdatetime
```

I don't get all the results I'd hoped for, unlike running

```
  SELECT DISTINCT time_series_only.closesthourdatetime
  FROM measdata.time_series_only
```

where I do.

I'm guessing this is because pgsql datetimes are actually numeric values with the times as a portion of a day, so the milliseconds might not match exactly which I didn't care about.

Is there a way to query this, but specify to nearest second or minute
    WHERE time_series_only.datetime = time_series_only.closesthourdatetime
without a convoluted and presumably slow query like this? :

```
  SELECT DISTINCT time_series_only.closesthourdatetime
  FROM measdata.time_series_only
  --WHERE 
  --time_series_only.datetime = time_series_only.closesthourdatetime
  /*EXTRACT (YEAR FROM time_series_only.datetime)   = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM time_series_only.closesthourdatetime)
  AND EXTRACT (MONTH FROM time_series_only.datetime)    = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM time_series_only.closesthourdatetime)
  AND EXTRACT (DAY FROM time_series_only.datetime)  = EXTRACT(DAY FROM time_series_only.closesthourdatetime)
  AND EXTRACT (HOUR FROM time_series_only.datetime)     = EXTRACT(HOUR FROM time_series_only.closesthourdatetime)
  AND EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM time_series_only.datetime) = EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM time_series_only.closesthourdatetime)
  AND EXTRACT (SECOND FROM time_series_only.datetime) = EXTRACT(SECOND FROM time_series_only.closesthourdatetime)
```

Comment: `date_trunc()` may do what you want.

Comment: What is the  closesthourdatetime for `01/01/2005 00:29:59`? Is it rounded down or up?

Comment: 01/01/2005 00:29:59 would be rounded down

Comment: Drat... revising answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can get expected results with this where clause:

```
WHERE datetime >= closesthourdatetime - INTERVAL '30 MINUTE'
AND   datetime <  closesthourdatetime + INTERVAL '30 MINUTE'
```

Here closesthourdatetime `01/01/2005 01:00:00` will match all datetime in the range `[01/01/2005 00:30:00, 01/01/2005 01:30:00)` where the second date is exclusive.

[SQL Fiddle for test/edge cases](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9d64e/1)